# How many have I killed today?

Tags: world-of-tanks

World of tanks is currently running a promotion where players get 300000 credits after scoring 30 kills in a day, and a day of premium after accumulating 50000 XP in a single day.

Is there an easy way to see the progress too these goals?

Comment: I don't know if they show you XP per kill, or if it is 30 kills in a match but, In my experience of no GUI identifier of kills, a pen and pad of paper tracking kills and XP at the end of a match works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 8.8 released in September 2013 there is now a 'Missions' button on the main garage interface that tracks tour progress.

In addition the post battle report now also shows your mission progress when relevant.

It's in the [release notes](http://worldoftanks.eu/en/content/guide/release-notes/release-notes-88/):

> Significantly expanded the functionality of missions. An interface with description and current mission status has now been added to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to check your "Service record" at the beginning of your session, check Destroyed and Total Experience values there and make a note of them.

Tools like http://www.wotlabs.com and http://www.noobmeter.com can also be used to check the statistics you had in the beginning of the sessions as they are updated once a day.